# How to add "most recent emails from this user" to Gmail inbox as a sidebar

Tags: gmail

I use and love gmail. However, since i use email for customer support, I'm always doing a cross reference lookup via the search feature to see my past conversations with the person whose email I'm reading.

I'd love to have a right sidebar widget that shows me, for any email I choose to read, the list of previous conversations/emails with that person.

Is this possible? I'm using Chrome

Ideally, this sidebar would bump or replace the contextual ads that now display over there.

Comment: Previously, when hovering over a sender's name on gmail, the popup included a link/button "recent conversations" (between the "send email", "send video" and "schedule event" icons)  which I could click to list all threads/email from (or including?) that person/email address. This very useful feature is gone, and the sidebar that can clumsily be opened only shows 3 most recent conversation and no link to the the whole list. Do you regret this and/or found a different way to easily search for the sender's mail (without manually copy & paste insto the search box)? Thx!

Answer (score 3):

A sidebar widget would be nice, but short of that, there is a nice built-in feature for looking at past conversations with someone. When you're reading the email from them, hold the mouse over the contact's name and a small popup dialog will appear. In that, click "More" and a small menu will drop down. There's a button there that says "Recent Conversations." This should at least save you the time of having to go to the search bar and typing in their email address.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you're looking for but this Greasemonkey script will bring up recent conversations by a specified user.

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/6929

Comment: Love it, but it does not work for chrome yet apparently. I'm addicted to chrome's simplicity and speed, having left IE for Firefox long ago. I didn't think anything could best FF, then I discovered chrome.

Comment: It's fairly simple to make Greasemonkey scripts work in Chrome. You @Scott should leave a comment there to ask for Chrome support!

Answer (score 0):

[Mailbrowser](http://mailbrowser.com) also claims to have a browser addon that'll work with Firefox and IE (no Chrome yet, AFAIK) that is almost like [Xobni for Outlook](http://xobni.com)

It displays more info about the contact and has quick links in a sidebar.